# Errors when using template literals in Vue

Tags: vue.js, template-literals, reactivesearch

I have the following in my Vue project:

```
:customHighlight = `(props) => ({
          highlight: {
              pre_tags: ['<mark>'],
              post_tags: ['</mark>'],
              fields: {
                  text: {},
                  title: {},
              },
              number_of_fragments: 0,
          },
      })`
```

and I am getting the following errors:

```
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
error: 'v-bind' directives require an attribute value (vue/valid-v-bind) at src\views\Home.vue:24:7:
  22 |         ]"
  23 |
> 24 |       :customHighlight = `(props) => ({
     |       ^
  25 |           highlight: {
  26 |               pre_tags: ['<mark>'],
  27 |               post_tags: ['</mark>'],


error: Parsing error: unexpected-character-in-unquoted-attribute-value (vue/no-parsing-error) at src\views\Home.vue:24:26:
  22 |         ]"
  23 |
> 24 |       :customHighlight = `(props) => ({
     |                          ^
  25 |           highlight: {
  26 |               pre_tags: ['<mark>'],
  27 |               post_tags: ['</mark>'],


error: Parsing error: Line 1: Unterminated template

> 1 | 0(`(props))
    |    ^ (vue/no-parsing-error) at src\views\Home.vue:24:27:
  22 |         ]"
  23 |
> 24 |       :customHighlight = `(props) => ({
     |                           ^
  25 |           highlight: {
  26 |               pre_tags: ['<mark>'],
  27 |               post_tags: ['</mark>'],


error: Parsing error: unexpected-equals-sign-before-attribute-name (vue/no-parsing-error) at src\views\Home.vue:24:35:
  22 |         ]"
  23 |
> 24 |       :customHighlight = `(props) => ({
     |                                   ^
  25 |           highlight: {
  26 |               pre_tags: ['<mark>'],
  27 |               post_tags: ['</mark>'],
```

I am getting this snippet from: https://opensource.appbase.io/reactive-manual/vue/search-components/datasearch.html

I am a bit stuck and I am thinking that there is something wrong with the way he template literal is stuctured?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the whole component declaration like in the example you linked to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you've copied this from does appear to be wrong.

In JavaScript backticks are often used to create strings that span multiple lines. This makes them very useful for writing Vue templates.

However...

This particular example isn't in JavaScript, it's HTML. HTML attribute values need to be surrounded by single or double quotes, not backticks. Attribute values can span multiple lines without needing any other special treatment.

So, in short, just replace the backticks with double quotes, `"`, and everything should be fine.

Comment: Thank you Skirtle, I tried that and got no errors. The only problem I have now is that my <mark></mark> HTML is escaped and not rendered as HTML

Comment: Nevermind, I had to use v-html instead of curly braces. thanks!